# jQuery - Add a comma only if a there is a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can’t quite figure out the best way to do this but I have a series of values that are being fed into my jquery plugin. I’m following the convention of adding a space after each value. I then grab the jquery parameters and attempt to add a **‘,’** to each one so that it can be feed into a json call. The problem is that if I add a **‘,’** in place of the space and the value returned from the variable in the plugin is empty I get multiple commas that I don’t need. (i.e. ,,podcast). How would I only add a comma if there is a value in my variable?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#gallery').mediaFilters({
        mediaType: '${article} ${podcast} ${image}',
        headerType: '${internet} ${cloud} ${background}',
    });
});
```

JQUERY to send to JSON:

```
var mediaType = "&mediaType=" + opts.mediaType.split(/[ ]/).join(',');
var headerType = "&headerType=" + opts.headerType.split(/[ ]/).join(',');
```

Comment: EDIT: use `.replace(/\s+/,' ')` before `.split` and suppress multiple empty values.

Comment: Once you've got your final string ",, podcast" can you run a string query to remove any commas that appear consecutively and if there is a comma at the start and end of the string to remove them too? The final string should then be what you're after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/ +/` will match multiple spaces, so the input `a   b` will turn into `a,b`.

The regex `/^ *| *$/` will match the spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

Together, here is code that will replace those with a comma, and remove the beginning and end spaces.

```
var mediaType = "&mediaType=" + opts.mediaType.replace(/^ *| *$/g,'').replace(/ +/g,',');
var headerType = "&headerType=" + opts.headerType.replace(/^ *| *$/g,'').replace(/ +/g,',');
```